# R package / function for comparing descriptive stats for multiple datasets

Tags: r, statistics, anova

I have a data set that is split into 2 pieces for training and testing a predictive model.  The performance is very different between the 2 subsets and so I'd like to go in and compare the descriptive stats for the 2 sets.

I know there are several functions for doing this for a single data set (ie summary, describe, etc.) but don't know of any that's built for comparing 2 sets.

Are there any functions built to combine the descriptive stats (mean, median, max, min, frequently occurring values, NA's, etc) from 2 or more data sets and allow for easy comparison?

Ideally something list this:

```
Stat          Set1         Set2
Mean           2.34         3.44
Median         2.55         1.99
Min            0.00         0.20
Max            14.34        22.32
```

Comment: `sapply(list_of_your_data_frames, FUN = function_that_produces_your_stats)`?

Comment: If they're in the same data.frame with an indicator to separate them, then `by` is pretty nice. example: `by(mtcars, mtcars["cyl"], summary)`.